# Convert panel data wide to long by two variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in Python that I am trying to convert from a wide dataset like this:

| ID | Name | 2007 | 2008 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | 324 | 412 |
| 2 | Becky | 123 | 422 |
| 3 | Lizzie | 332 | 564 |

To a long dataset such as this.

| ID | Name | Year | Var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | 2007 | 324 |
| 1 | Andy | 2008 | 412 |
| 2 | Becky | 2007 | 123 |
| 2 | Becky | 2008 | 422 |
| 3 | Lizzie | 2007 | 332 |
| 3 | Lizzie | 2008 | 564 |

Unfortunately can't use pivot due to the two identification columns and multiple observations for each year. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `df.melt(['ID', 'Name'])`

Answer (score 0):

Can't use `pivot` because this is actually a `melt` operation:

```
out = (df.melt(
            id_vars=["ID", "Name"], 
            value_vars=["2007", "2008"], 
            var_name="Year", 
            value_name="Var"
        )
        .sort_values(["ID", "Year"]))

print(out)
   ID    Name  Year  Var
0   1    Andy  2007  324
3   1    Andy  2008  412
1   2   Becky  2007  123
4   2   Becky  2008  422
2   3  Lizzie  2007  332
5   3  Lizzie  2008  564
```